# How to take a string as input and then print each word in a new line

Tags: c, arrays, string, debugging

> i want to to take a string as a input and then print each word in a
>   new line.
>
> **Condition is:** printed word must be stored in a array and every word will be removed from array after printing it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char s[100], tmp[20];
  int i=0,space=0,k;
  scanf("%[^\n]", s);

  while(s[i]!='\0'){
    if(space==0) tmp[i]=s[i]; //copying word only
    else tmp[i-(k+1)]=s[i];   //copying word only

    if((s[i]==' ')||(s[i+1]=='\0')){
      tmp[i+1]='\0';
      space++;
      printf("%s\n", tmp); //printing word from an array

      for(int j=0; tmp[j]!='\0'; j++) tmp[j]='\0'; //erasing this array for reuse
      k=i++; //(i++) for skip space and 'k' for starting index from tmp[0]
      if(s[i]=='\0') i--; //when null don't need to increase i for skip space
    }
  i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand the issue?

Comment: Why store the  data if you're just going to delete it?  The only thing you need to do is insert `\n` in the proper place.  No need for excess storage.

Comment: Never use `scanf()` to a string with no field width like that.  Avoid overflowing `s` by using `scanf("%99[^\n]", s);`, or simply `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);`.  And don't ignore the return value - that's crucial information you need to use before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explicitly violates your condition, but the condition is inappropriate and I think it's worthwhile for the reader to see how to do this without it.  The primary benefit of this approach is that you do not impose arbitrary limits on the input length.  (In the original code, input must not exceed 100 bytes.)  I make the assumption that your problem statement is simply to implement `tr -s '[[:space:]]' \\n`, in which case you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Simple implementation of tr -s '[[:space:]]' \\n */

int
main(void)
{
        int in_space = 0;
        int c;
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF  ) {
                if(isspace(c)) {
                        if( !in_space )
                                putchar('\n');
                        in_space = 1;
                } else {
                        in_space = 0;
                        putchar(c);
                }
        }
        if(!in_space)
                putchar('\n');
        return 0;
}
```

Which can be simplified somewhat (IMO, the above is excessively redundant):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Simple implementation of tr -s '[[:space:]]' \\n */

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        int last = '\n';
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF  ) {
                c = isspace(c) ? '\n' : c;
                if( c != '\n' || last != '\n' )
                        putchar(c);
                last = c;
        }
        if( last != '\n' )
                putchar(c);
        return 0;
}
```

or even:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Simple implementation of tr -s '[[:space:]]' \\n */

void
dedup(int c)
{
        static int last = '\n';
        if( c != '\n' || last != '\n' )
                putchar(c);
        last = c;
}

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF  ) {
                dedup( isspace(c) ? '\n' : c);
        }
        dedup('\n');
        return 0;
}
```